# OpenLiteSpeed django app broken after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: python, django, openlitespeed

I was running an Ubuntu Image of litespeed django application,

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/litespeedtechnologies.openlitespeed-django

It was 20.04 LTS, I tried to do a release upgrade which was successful to 22.04 but the OpenLiteSpeed server now fails to run.

The request keeps on spinning in the browser and after some time errors with 503.
There is no entry in the **/usr/local/lsws/logs/stderr.log** file regarding the 503 error

Steps I already tried:

1. Reinstalled python virtual environment
2. Re-installed the dependencies
3. Tried running the application on 8000 port using **python3 manage.py runserver** command and it works on the browser as expected
4. updated the vhost file on the Server with the update python runtime path from 3.8 to 3.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recompile the wsgi-lsapi**

Once you upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, please recompile the wsgi-lsapi binary with the new system.

Get the [Python LSAPI version here](https://www.litespeedtech.com/open-source/litespeed-sapi/lsapi-release-log.). Replace the VERSION below with the version number you find there (like 2.1).

```
curl -O http://www.litespeedtech.com/packages/lsapi/wsgi-lsapi-VERSION.tgz
tar xf wsgi-lsapi-2.1.tgz
cd wsgi-lsapi-2.1
python3 ./configure.py
make
mv lswsgi /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/
```

Then restart the Web Server

```
systemctl restart lsws
```

Comment: Thanks this did solve the problem. Make sure to change the python references as well.